# Replacing value in list based on input and dictionary ;-;

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, replace

I need to print out a 4x4 table that's labeled ( A   B   C   D ) horizontally and 1234 vertically and ask the user to place a randomly generated number in the table (eg. A1, B2)

```
num = randomly generated number

table = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
ans = input('where would you like to place it?')
```

I used a dictionary to assign A1 : table[0][0] and so on
Tried to replace the value with:

```
if ans in dictionary:
    table.replace(dictionary.get(ans),num)
```

It's not working for me but I only understand how to do it this way.

Comment: Have you checked if the program enters your `if` clause? Maybe your input is different from what you expect. Try putting a `print` in the `if` and see if it shows up in the console.

Comment: I'll try it thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = 'randomly generated number'

table = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

ss = {'B1': [0,1]}
ans = input('where would you like to place it: ')

index_ = ss[ans][0]
columns_ = ss[ans][1]
table[index_][columns_] = num
print(table)
```

Do you think it can meet your requirements.

Comment: thank you so much!! :D It works really well!! Can I ask if its possible to do the same but with a nested list instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. The index of array is the same as that of list. As long as the index is OK, you can manage the index with list or dictionary.